# How to find which candidate of a srcset is in use?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got an image with a srcset like:

```
<img src="1x.png" srcset="2x.png 2x, 4x.png 4x">
```

I'd like to find out which of the candidates is currently being displayed, ideally I'd get back `2x.png` or `4x.png` depending on which image the browser has picked.

I thought `img.src` would do that but as far as I can tell from experimentation, `img.src` returns `1x.png` (or rather the resolved full url to 1x.png), and `img.srcset` and `img.getAttribute('srcset')` both return the entire srcset definition

Comment: with me it is working fine, you mean it is returning the whole set together?

Comment: @YehiaAwad I mean it is returning the value in src, not a value in srcset

Comment: have you tried img.getAttribute("srcset"); ?

Comment: @YehiaAwad yeah i updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, I guess what you are looking for is :

```
img.currentSrc;
```